# pyspark duplicates in workers. Count words in text file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have **3** workers running with a single master.

It's a **standalone** system

here is the script

```
import sys
 
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # create Spark context with necessary configuration
        conf = SparkConf()
        conf.setMaster('spark://172.31.60.190:7077')
        conf.setAppName('spark-basic')
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)    
    # read data from text file and split each line into words
        words = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/sparkscripts/files/").flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
    
    # count the occurrence of each word
        wordCounts = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a +b)
    
    # save the counts to output
        wordCounts.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/home/ubuntu/sparkscripts/files/output/")
```

A single file gets created with word counts for each word but the word gets repeated exactly 3 times e g the word **'nibh'**

```
('on', 1)
('nibh', 2871678)
('amet.', 1147222)
('Pulvinar', 337496)
('Ridiculus', 51053)
('Rhoncus', 215521)
('nibh', 9234234)
('quam.', 453811)
('will', 1)
('cras', 2108764)
('dignissim.', 303452)
('iaculis', 1072101)
('bibendum.', 331816
('nibh', 234234)
```

This duplication happens for all words. May I know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: It is not ah HDFS file? Copied 3 times thus once to each worker? If so, then that is the issue.

Comment: @thebluephantom It is just an ordinary text file. But if it is copied 3 times then the word count should be same, but the word count is different ('nibh', 2871678) ('nibh', 9234234) and ('nibh', 234234)

Comment: Yes each worker is appending its own results. How to bring all results from all workers into a single result without duplicates?

Comment: interesting. you copied the same file 3 times? why not use the hdfs put and see results.

Comment: @thebluephantom Not sure what do you mean by copied the file 3 times?

Comment: r u using hdfs. looks like a posix linux file system

Comment: the logic is fine